# the meaning of so much for

Tags: meaning

I found a post asking the meaning of **so much for** on StackExchange, however, I still can't quite get the idea of the following phrase.

> - Text from Harrington... thanking you for tickets to the game. Yeah, **so much for** a burst pipe.

It's the line from an American drama, the background is a man lied to a woman that his colleague Harrington got a burst pipe at home and couldn't make it today, the woman found out the truth later and said that line angrily.

Sorry for my poor expression, I'm an English learner and really want to figure out the exact meaning of **so much for** in this line.

According to CDO, **so much for something** means:

> used to express disappointment at the fact that a situation is not as you thought it was.

But I think it's not enough for understanding this line and translating it into my mother language.

Answer (score 4):

"So much for + [thing]" means the thing in question is no longer true, no longer valid, no longer believed, no longer counted on/trusted in, no longer working, no longer possible, etc.

Very often that involves elements of disappointment. "My car broke. So much for my plans to drive to Vegas!" --> My plan to drive to Vegas is no longer possible because my car broke (and that's disappointing).

Here's the [definition from wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so_much_for), which gives a greater range of meanings/usages than your source:

> An expression of dismissiveness, disappointment, disregard, or resignation; something said upon rejecting, giving up on, quitting, or disposing of something.
>
> For years, Volkswagen cars were designed to cheat on emissions tests.
>   So much for "German engineering".
>
> Well, I guess it'll never work. So much for that idea.

Note that the first example above shows rejecting/dismissing an idea, and the second example suggests some disappointment.

In the case you cited from the American play the woman is rejecting the burst pipe explanation, indicating that it is no longer believable.